# UIActivityViewController completion handler shows 'completed' even if user wasn't able to log into Tumblr or other app

Tags: ios, tumblr, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using completionWithItemsHandler to determine if selectedItems were posted to Tumblr. I want to present a 'Success!' alert if the post was complete but completionHandler returns 'completed' even if the user wasn't able to log into Tumblr.  That is,user goes through the steps of selecting items, opening activity view, and selecting Tumblr -->  this opens the Tumblr app and asks for a log in.  If the user presses 'cancel' and goes back to my app, the completionHandler says the activity was 'completed'.  Is there any way to determine if post was successful?  Any way to test if the user was able to log into the app?  Any suggestions for dealing with 'success' alerts when there can be these types of problems?
Here is the completion Handler

```
activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *error){

    if (error)
    {
        //NSError *error;

        alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error sharing items" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *errorAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
            NSLog(@"Error sharing items: %@", error);
        }];

        [alertController addAction:errorAction];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (completed)
    {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

        if ([self.giftID isEqualToString:@"general"]||[self.giftEntity.giftThanked isEqualToString:@"YES"])
        {
            alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
           // NSLog(@"OK action");
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }];

        [alertController addAction:okAction];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

        if (![self.giftID isEqualToString:@"general"]&&[self.giftEntity.giftThanked isEqualToString:@"NO"])
        {
            alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle message:@"Mark gift as 'Thanked'?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *yesAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"YES", @"yes action") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                self.giftEntity.giftThanked = @"YES";
                [self.giftBusObj saveEntities];

                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }];

            UIAlertAction *noAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"NO", @"no action") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                self.giftEntity.giftThanked = @"NO";
                [self.giftBusObj saveEntities];

                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }];

            [alertController addAction:noAction];
            [alertController addAction:yesAction];

            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

        //Deselect all items in stvc

        self.textShare = 0;
        self.cardButton.selected = NO;

        self.textImageBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.cardImageBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [spcvc selectPhotosNone];

        [self viewDidLoad];
    }

    else
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"activity controller - not 'completed' nor 'error'" );
    }
};
```

Comment: can you post the code of completion handler?